# vbulletin 3.8: new sub forum added via mysql won't be displayed

Tags: mysql, sql, vbulletin

How to make vbulletin display sub forum added via mysql?

I added a new sub forum in vbulletin by inserting a new row in "forum" table. However, this sub forum isn't displayed in the page. Then I tried adding sub forum in admincp, after that, the page display both recently added sub forum and the one I added via mysql.

I really don't get it. Does adding sub forum in admincp do anything other than inserting a new row in "forum" table to make it displayed in vbulletin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that when you add forums through the control panel, it automatically rebuilds the information.

After you create a forum directly in the database, try rebuilding the forum information via ACP > Maintenance > Update Counters